# Deny users access to site home, allow access to document library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am using SharePoint Foundation 2010 and working on managing permissions at the moment. I would like all users to have access to the document library "Shared Documents". I would like only users part of the AD groups "Admin" and "Doc Admin" to see anything else on the site. If the user is not part of those two groups and tried to go directly to the SharePoint site I would like an access denied error. But, it they go directly to the document library, they should have access.

I have two groups, for complexity lets call them Group A and Group B. Every user in AD is part of Group A or Group B (This includes the Admin and Doc Admin groups who should be able to access the site directly)

I tried to make a change to the user policy regarding those 4 groups but it doesn't seem to be cooperating.

Anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Break permissions on the DocLib and assign the everyone groups rights to the list.  On the site, grant permissions only to Admin and DocAdmin, no one else